# How to calculate overlapping subscription days from orders with sql-server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, overlapping, cumulative-sum

I have an ordertable with orders. I want to calculate the amount of subscriptiondays for each user (preffered in a set-based way) for a specific day.

```
create table #orders (orderid int, userid int, subscriptiondays int, orderdate date)
insert into #orders
    select 1, 2, 10, '2011-01-01'
    union 
    select 2, 1, 10, '2011-01-10'
    union 
    select 3, 1, 10, '2011-01-15'
    union 
    select 4, 2, 10, '2011-01-15'

declare @currentdate date = '2011-01-20'

--userid 1 is expected to have 10 subscriptiondays left
(since there is 5 left when the seconrd order is placed)
--userid 2 is expected to have 5 subscriptionsdays left
```

I'm sure this has been done before, I just dont know what to search for. 
Pretty much like a running total?

So when I set @currentdate to '2011-01-20' I want this result:

```
userid      subscriptiondays
1           10
2           5
```

When I set @currentdate to '2011-01-25'

```
userid      subscriptiondays
1           5
2           0
```

When I set @currentdate to '2011-01-11'

```
userid      subscriptiondays
1           9
2           0
```

Thanks!

Comment: To claify, you want to difference in days between your parameter and the order date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would need to use a [recursive common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx).

EDIT: I've also added a procedural implementation further below instead of using a recursive common table expression.  I recommend using that procedural approach, as I think there may be a number of data scenarios that the recursive CTE query that I've included probably doesn't handle.

The query below gives the correct answers for the scenarios that you've provided, but you would probably want to think up some additional complex scenarios and see whether there are any bugs.

For instance, I have a feeling that this query may break down if you have multiple previous orders overlapping with a later order.

```
with CurrentOrders (UserId, SubscriptionDays, StartDate, EndDate) as
(
    select
        userid,
        sum(subscriptiondays),
        min(orderdate),
        dateadd(day, sum(subscriptiondays), min(orderdate))
    from #orders
    where
        #orders.orderdate <= @currentdate
        -- start with the latest order(s)
        and not exists (
            select 1
            from #orders o2
        where
            o2.userid = #orders.userid
            and o2.orderdate <= @currentdate
            and o2.orderdate > #orders.orderdate
        )
    group by
        userid

    union all

    select
        #orders.userid,
        #orders.subscriptiondays,
        #orders.orderdate,
        dateadd(day, #orders.subscriptiondays, #orders.orderdate)
    from #orders
    -- join any overlapping orders
    inner join CurrentOrders on
        #orders.userid = CurrentOrders.UserId
        and #orders.orderdate < CurrentOrders.StartDate
        and dateadd(day, #orders.subscriptiondays, #orders.orderdate) > CurrentOrders.StartDate
)
select
    UserId,
    sum(SubscriptionDays) as TotalSubscriptionDays,
    min(StartDate),
    sum(SubscriptionDays) - datediff(day, min(StartDate), @currentdate) as RemainingSubscriptionDays
from CurrentOrders
group by
    UserId
;
```

Philip mentioned a concern about the recursion limit on common table expressions.  Below is a procedural alternative using a table variable and a while loop, which I believe accomplishes the same thing.

While I've verified that this alternative code does work, at least for the sample data provided, I'd be glad to hear anyone's comments on this approach.  Good idea?  Bad idea?  Any concerns to be aware of?

```
declare @ModifiedRows int

declare @CurrentOrders table
(
    UserId int not null,
    SubscriptionDays int not null,
    StartDate date not null,
    EndDate date not null
)

insert into @CurrentOrders
select
    userid,
    sum(subscriptiondays),
    min(orderdate),
    min(dateadd(day, subscriptiondays, orderdate))
from #orders
where
    #orders.orderdate <= @currentdate
    -- start with the latest order(s)
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from #orders o2
        where
            o2.userid = #orders.userid
            and o2.orderdate <= @currentdate
            -- there does not exist any other order that surpasses it
            and dateadd(day, o2.subscriptiondays, o2.orderdate) > dateadd(day, #orders.subscriptiondays, #orders.orderdate)
    )
group by
    userid

set @ModifiedRows = @@ROWCOUNT


-- perform an extra update here in case there are any additional orders that were made after the start date but before the specified @currentdate
update co set
    co.SubscriptionDays = co.SubscriptionDays + #orders.subscriptiondays
from @CurrentOrders co
inner join #orders on
    #orders.userid = co.UserId
    and #orders.orderdate <= @currentdate
    and #orders.orderdate >= co.StartDate
    and dateadd(day, #orders.subscriptiondays, #orders.orderdate) < co.EndDate


-- Keep attempting to update rows as long as rows were updated on the previous attempt
while(@ModifiedRows > 0)
begin
    update co set
        SubscriptionDays = co.SubscriptionDays + overlap.subscriptiondays,
        StartDate = overlap.orderdate
    from @CurrentOrders co
    -- join any overlapping orders
    inner join (
        select
            #orders.userid,
            sum(#orders.subscriptiondays) as subscriptiondays,
            min(orderdate) as orderdate
        from #orders
        inner join @CurrentOrders co2 on
            #orders.userid = co2.UserId
            and #orders.orderdate < co2.StartDate
            and dateadd(day, #orders.subscriptiondays, #orders.orderdate) > co2.StartDate
        group by
            #orders.userid
    ) overlap on
        overlap.userid = co.UserId

    set @ModifiedRows = @@ROWCOUNT
end

select
    UserId,
    sum(SubscriptionDays) as TotalSubscriptionDays,
    min(StartDate),
    sum(SubscriptionDays) - datediff(day, min(StartDate), @currentdate) as RemainingSubscriptionDays
from @CurrentOrders
group by
    UserId
```

EDIT2: I've made some adjustments to the code above to address various special cases, such as if there just happen to be two orders for a user that both end on the same date.

For instance, changing the setup data to the following caused issues with the original code, which I've now corrected:

```
insert into #orders
    select 1, 2, 10, '2011-01-01'
    union 
    select 2, 1, 10, '2011-01-10'
    union 
    select 3, 1, 10, '2011-01-15'
    union 
    select 4, 2, 6, '2011-01-15'
    union 
    select 5, 2, 4, '2011-01-17'
```

EDIT3: I've made some additional adjustments to address other special cases.  In particular, the previous code ran into issues with the following setup data, which I've now corrected:

```
insert into #orders
    select 1, 2, 10, '2011-01-01'
    union 
    select 2, 1, 6, '2011-01-10'
    union 
    select 3, 1, 10, '2011-01-15'
    union 
    select 4, 2, 10, '2011-01-15'
    union 
    select 5, 1, 4, '2011-01-12'
```

Answer (score 0):

If my clarifying comment/question is correct, then you want to use DATEDIFF:

```
DATEDIFF(dd, orderdate,  @currentdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, we need calculate summ of subscriptiondays minus days beetwen first subscrible date and @currentdate like:

```
select userid, 
       sum(subsribtiondays)-
       DATEDIFF('dd', 
                (select min(orderdate) 
                 from #orders as a 
                 where a.userid=userid),  @currentdate)
from #orders
where orderdate <= @currentdata
group by userid
```

Comment: I thought about this approach as well, but I think this breaks down when a user has a gap between subscriptions.  i.e. if the user has a previous subscription that expired, then that subscription needs to be excluded from consideration.  That seems to be what makes this problem tricky.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the problem:

- On day X, customer buys a “span” of subscription days (i.e. good for N days)
- The span starts on the day of purchase and is good for X through day X + (N - 1)...  but see below
- If customer purchases a second span **after** the first expires (or any new span after all existing spans expire), repeat process. (A single 10-day purchase 30 days ago has no impact on a second purhcase made today.)
- If customer purchases a span while existing span(s) are still in effect, the new span applies to `day immediately after end of current span(s)` through `that date + (N – 1)`
- This is iterative. If customer buys 10-day spans on Jan 1st, Jan 2nd, and Jan 3rd, it would look something like:

  As of 1st: Jan 1 – Jan 10

  As of 2nd: Jan 1 – Jan 10, Jan 11 – Jan 20 (in effect, Jan 1 to Jan 20)

  As of 3rd: Jan 1 – Jan 10, Jan 11 – Jan 20, Jan 21 – Jan 30 (in effect, Jan 1 to Jan 30)

If this is indeed the problem, then it is a horrible problem to solve in T-SQL. To deterimine the “effective span” of a given purchase, you have to calculate the effective span of all prior purchases *in the order that they were purchased*, because of that overall cumulative effect. This is a trivial problem with 1 user and 3 rows, but non-trivial with thousands of users with dozens of purchases (which, presumably, is what you want).

I would solve it like so:

- Add column `EffectiveDate` of datatype `date` to the table
- Build a one-time process to walk through every row user-by-user and orderdate by orderdate, and calculate the EffectiveDate as discussed above
- Modify the process used to insert the data to calculate the EffectiveDate at the time a new entry is made. Done this way, you’d only ever have to reference the most recent purchase made by that user.
- Wrangle out subsequent issues regarding deleting (cancelled?) or updating (mis-set?) orders

I may be wrong, but I don't see any way to address this using set-based tactics. (Recursive CTEs and the like would work, but they can only recurse to so many levels, and we don't know the limit for this problem -- let alone how often you'll need to run it, or how well it must perform.) I'll watch and upvote anyone who solves this without recursion!

And of course this only applies if my understanding of the problem is correct. If not, please disregard.

Comment: Despite my poor description, you picked everything up. Thanks for helping me describe the problem!